# Sanitize gem doesn't like colon inside href attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sanitize

Using the Sanitize gem, I'm cleaning some HTML. In the href attribute of my anchor tags, I wish to parse the following:

`<a href="#fn:1">1</a>`

This is required for implementing [footnotes using the Kramdown gem](http://kramdown.rubyforge.org/quickref.html#footnotes).

However, Sanitize doesn't appear to like the colon inside the href attribute. It simply outputs `<a>1</a>` instead, skipping the href attribute altogether.

My sanitize code looks like this:

```
# Setup whitelist of html elements, attributes, and protocols that are allowed.
allowed_elements = ['h2', 'a', 'img', 'p', 'ul', 'ol', 'li', 'strong', 'em', 'cite', 
  'blockquote', 'code', 'pre', 'dl', 'dt', 'dd', 'br', 'hr', 'sup', 'div']
allowed_attributes = {'a' => ['href', 'rel', 'rev'], 'img' => ['src', 'alt'], 
  'sup' => ['id'], 'div' => ['class'], 'li' => ['id']}
allowed_protocols = {'a' => {'href' => ['http', 'https', 'mailto', :relative]}}

# Clean text of any unwanted html tags.
html = Sanitize.clean(html, :elements => allowed_elements, :attributes => allowed_attributes, 
  :protocols => allowed_protocols)
```

Is there a way to get Sanitize to accept a colon in the href attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Sanitize doing the safest thing by default. It assumes that the portion of the URL before the `:` is a protocol (or a scheme in the terminology of RFC 1738), and since `#fn` isn't in the protocol whitelist, the entire `href` attribute is removed.

You can allow URLs like this by adding `#fn` to the protocol whitelist:

```
allowed_protocols = {'a' => {'href' => ['#fn', 'http', 'https', 'mailto', :relative]}}
```

Comment: To whoever downvoted this: Ryan is the guy who _wrote_ Sanitize. If anyone knows the right answer, it’s probably him.

Comment: This worked great, thanks! Just a heads up to anyone else implementing this solution, you'll need to add `'#fnref'` for the footnote references that link back up to the footnote as well. E.g. `allowed_protocols = {'a' => {'href' => ['#fn', '#fnref', 'http', 'https', 'mailto', :relative]}}`